# Cannot read property 'set' of undefined of a defined Map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm working with ES6 for the first time, and I read some stuff about maps. From what I understand, this should be well within the possibility of ES6:

```
export class Elements {

    constructor() {
        this.elements = new Map();
        this.attachListeners();
    }

    textElement () {
        this.elements.set((elements.length + 1), new TextElement());
    }

    attachListeners () {
        document.getElementById('addText').addEventListener('click', this.textElement);
    }
}
```

However, when I click the `addText` element, I get the following in my console

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined at HTMLDivElement.textElement`

I tried swapping the `Map` with a `Set`, an `Array` and an `Object`, however, that same error kept coming into my console.

How can it be that a simple operation like this isn't working?

Comment: See *Common problem: Using object methods as callbacks / event handlers* in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your listener, like this:

```
document.getElementById('addText').addEventListener('click', this.textElement.bind(this));
```

Otherwise, `this` refers to your 'addText' element in your `textElement` function.

Try `console.log(this)` in `textElement` with and without the `.bind(this)` and you'll understand what's happening.